# Whether or not (if/although)

Tags: whether-if

**"It is unknown whether or not he was telling the truth."**

This sentence means the same as -

"*It is unknown if he was telling the truth."*

"*It is unknown whether he was telling the truth."*

"*It is unknown whether he was telling the truth or not."*

Does it also mean:
**"It is unknown although he was telling the truth."**

Comment: Have you seen here: http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/if_and_whether.htm

Answer (score 2):

In all the examples above, the word "it" here is an empty subject to "whether or not he was telling the truth".

However in your question, the word "it" is not an empty subject to "even though he was telling the truth", it seems to mean other things.

So no, they are not the same. "Even though" changes the grammatical fucntion of the word "it".

Comment: When whether or not means regardless of whether, the or not part is required. So, with  "or not part", I think "It's unknown, whether or not he was telling the truth."  also means "Although he was telling the truth, It's unknown."

Comment: +1 This is exactly right. *It* in the final sentence refers to some preceding matter, and the *although* clause qualifies the assertion that "it" is unknown.